# Will artificial sweeteners work in a coffee syrup recipe?

Tags: substitutions, coffee, ingredient-selection, syrup, recipe-writing

Here’s the recipe for coffee syrup

> Ingredients for 1 cup of coffee syrup
>
> 2 cups sugar
> 1 cup strong coffee
>
> Directions
> Mix sugar with the coffee
> Boil mixture down to the consistency of thick syrup
>
> To use put 1-2 teaspoons in a cup of hot water and stir it around a few minutes.

Would sugar substitute work with this recipe as written?

Comment: This is supposed to be the civil war equilibent of instant coffee if it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, according to a website called [A Bar Above](https://www.abarabove.com/simple-syrup/), you *can* make a simple syrup (or "rich simple" apparently) using artificial sweetener, but you won't get the same end result. They tested 3 sweeteners they found, and would recommend sweet'n'low over splenda or equal sweeteners. The taste and aftertaste will be different, and it will depend on the sweetener.

That said, I would NOT expect an artificial sweetener based syrup to thicken like sugar would. You would just need to boil it for a set time and make sure it doesn't boil off or burn. Speaking of burning-- If it's an option, I would recommend getting a jar of instant coffee and mixing that in with the finished syrup instead of making it with actual brewed coffee. Boiling brewed coffee may well give you a bitter, scorched flavor.

My other big concern would just be shelf-life. Sugar actually acts as a preservative in high enough concentrations. (Have you ever accidentally eater years-old hard candy with no ill effect? Thank sugar, lol.) Looking around I don't see any information on how long a simple syrup made with artificial sweetener would last. Although if you use it everyday, you'd go through it pretty quickly...

Comment: Trouble is, if you're using a sugar substitute, you'll never get the water activity down to the point where mold and bacteria won't grow. Adding alcohol to 20% on the final product would cure the problem, and let you use concentrated Stevia to boot, but 40 proof coffee is probably not the waker upper you are looking for.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger unless it really really is.

Answer (score 1):

** WARNING : First find out if it is safe to heat Splenda-like sweeteners! **

I would rather try using honey + a little of lemon juice + instant coffee if you are looking for a syrup result...